# Calendar to show today's current date with the next 60 days

Tags: javascript

I have created a calendar that successfully displays todays current date. It also shows the remaining months however I am trying to change the functionality of the calendar so that it only shows the next 60 days from today's current date.

The code so far:

```
var todayDate = new Date();
var finalDate = new Date(todayDate)
finalDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() + 60)
var dayNumber = todayDate.getDate();
var month = todayDate.getMonth();
var year = todayDate.getFullYear();
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

var calendarTable = document.getElementById("calendar-body");

document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = months[month];
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = year;

function createCalendar(month, year) {
 var firstDay = new Date(year, month).getDay();
 var totalDays = daysInMonth(month, year);

 blankDates(firstDay);
 for (var day = 1; day <= totalDays; day++) {
   var cell = document.createElement("li");
   var cellText = document.createTextNode(day);
   if (
     dayNumber === day &&
     month === todayDate.getMonth() &&
     year === todayDate.getFullYear()
   ) {
     cell.classList.add("todays-day");
   }

   cell.setAttribute("data-day", day);
   cell.setAttribute("data-month", month);
   cell.setAttribute("data-year", year);

   cell.classList.add("singleDay");
   cell.appendChild(cellText);
   calendarTable.appendChild(cell);
 }
}

function daysInMonth(month, year) {
 return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
}

function blankDates(count) {
 for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
   var cell = document.createElement("li");
   var cellText = document.createTextNode("");
   cell.appendChild(cellText);
   calendarTable.appendChild(cell);
 }
}

createCalendar(month, year);
```

Any ideas would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the number of dates between two dates,

In this case is **finalDate** and **todayDate**

```
 var diff =  Math.floor(( Date.parse(finalDate) - Date.parse(todayDate)) / 86400000);
```

You get the difference days (or NaN if one or both could not be parsed). The parse date gived the result in milliseconds and to get it by day you have to divided it by 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

The output of the diff now is **60**

Then you add the diff variable into the for loop.

[Woking example](https://js-byvmp9.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.

But you could generate an array of the dates between now and 60 days.
Then loop through that array to build the calendar.
This way the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) functions can be used for each date in the array.

Here's a simple function to generate such array.

```js
function getDateRange(pStartDate, pDays) {
  let days = pDays || 1;
  let dates = [];
  let n = 0;
  let startDate = new Date(pStartDate.toISOString().slice(0,10));
  let endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (days * 86400000));

  do {
    dates.push(new Date(startDate.getTime() + (n * 86400000)));
    n++;
  } while (n <= days);
  let obj = {
     startDate : startDate,
     endDate : endDate,
     days : dates.length,
     dates : dates
  }
  return obj;
}

var dateRange = getDateRange(new Date(), 60);

console.log(dateRange.dates);
```